# send multiple arguments into reducer of different types

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to send 2 float arguments and one int argument to the reducer from csv file .
float values results are successfully loaded into HDFS but the int result not visible in the final output. and I verified that right values are coming back to context.write method but don't understand why int values are not displayed? Can any one please help me out.

```
public class MaxTemperature extends Configured implements Tool {

public static class MapMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, PairWritable>{

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        String regex = ",";//''single quote not applicable for comma.
        String[] val = value.toString().split(regex);

        FloatWritable[]  vv = new FloatWritable[2];
        vv[0]= new FloatWritable(Float.parseFloat(val[3]));
        vv[1]=new FloatWritable(Float.parseFloat(val[13]));

        int k= Integer.parseInt(val[17]);
        IntWritable kk = new IntWritable(k);                
        float dd=Float.parseFloat(val[3]);
        PairWritable ddd = new PairWritable();
        context.write(new Text(val[2]), ddd.set(vv[0], vv[1],kk));

    }

} 


 public static class PairWritable extends ArrayWritable implements Writable{


    public PairWritable() {
        super(FloatWritable.class);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private FloatWritable floatone;
     private FloatWritable floattwo;
     private IntWritable intone;


     public String toString() {

            String s = Float.toString(floatone.get());
            String  a=Float.toString(floattwo.get());
            String q = s+'\t'+a;  
            return q;
          }


    public PairWritable set(float f1, float f2, int k){
         FloatWritable ff1 = new FloatWritable(f1);
         FloatWritable ff2 = new FloatWritable(f2);
         IntWritable inq = new IntWritable(k);
         set(ff1, ff2,inq);
         return this;
     }

     public PairWritable set(FloatWritable f1, FloatWritable f2, IntWritable f3){
         this.floatone=f1;
         this.floattwo=f2;
         this.intone=f3;
         return this;
     }

     public float getone(){
         return floatone.get();
     }

     public float gettwo(){
         return floattwo.get();
     }

     public int getthreeint(){
         return intone.get();
     }

     public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
            out.writeFloat(floatone.get());
            out.writeFloat(floattwo.get());
            out.writeInt(intone.get());
        }

        public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            floatone = new FloatWritable(in.readFloat());
            floattwo = new FloatWritable(in.readFloat());
            intone= new IntWritable(in.readInt());
        }

 }



public static class Mapreducers extends Reducer<Text,PairWritable, Text,PairWritable>{

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<PairWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{


        float sumone =0;
        float sumtwo=0;
        int sumthree=0;

        for(PairWritable dd: values){
        sumone+=dd.getone();
        sumtwo+=dd.gettwo();
        sumthree+=dd.getthreeint();

        }

        //FloatWritable result1 = new FloatWritable(sumone);
        //FloatWritable result2 = new FloatWritable(sumtwo);
        //IntWritable result3 = new IntWritable(sumthree);
        PairWritable ddd = new PairWritable();
        context.write(key, ddd.set(sumone, sumtwo,sumthree));


}

}


public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Job job = new Job();
    job.setJarByClass(MaxTemperature.class);
    job.setJobName("MaxTemperature");

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(args[0]), conf);

    if(fs.exists(new Path(args[1]))){
        fs.delete(new Path(args[1]),true);
    }

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setMapperClass(MapMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(Mapreducers.class);
    //job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
    job.setReducerClass(Mapreducers.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(PairWritable.class);

    return job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    int xx =1;
    xx = ToolRunner.run(new MaxTemperature(), args);
    System.exit(xx);    
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, I haven't converted int to string in toString method.

Used:

```
public String toString() {
        String s = Float.toString(floatone.get());
        String  a=Float.toString(floattwo.get());
        String q = s+'\t'+a;  
        return q;
      }
```

Supposed to use:

```
  public String toString() {

            String s = Float.toString(floatone.get());
            String  a=Float.toString(floattwo.get());
            String r=Integer.toString(intone.get());
            String q = s+'\t'+a+'\t'+r;  
            return q;
          }
```